# How to move cursor to end of paragraph or next blank line in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for a shortcut that would allow me to quickly move my cursor vertically to the end of the current paragraph, ie next blank line, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Does Ctrl-shift-enter do what you need?

Comment: no it does nothing more than enter alone, however I have resharper that's maybe because of it ?

Comment: I've got resharper as well.  It should create a new line after your current one and jump the cursor to it.  But not even sure that's what you want

Comment: jump to next blank line in the code

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to leave the Find window open and search regex for like \n\r.  I don't think macros exists anymore, so I doubt you can automate this.

Comment: Still no solution to this? Kinda lame, MS..